# Merge Postgres ranges that are not more than 5 minutes apart

Tags: postgresql, range

I have a `time_entries` table, where I use Postgres' 15 multi-range feature to merge overlapping and adjacent time ranges:

```
CREATE TABLE time_entries (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    contract_id bigint,
    "from" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    "to" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    range tsrange GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tsrange("from", "to")) STORED
);

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (1, 1, '2022-12-07T09:00', '2022-12-07T09:45');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T09:45', '2022-12-07T10:00');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T09:55', '2022-12-07T10:15');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T10:20', '2022-12-07T10:30');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T10:45', '2022-12-07T11:00');

SELECT contract_id, unnest(range_agg(range)) AS range FROM time_entries GROUP BY contract_id;
```

The current result is:

| contract_id | range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 09:00:00","2022-12-07 10:15:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:20:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:45:00","2022-12-07 11:00:00") |

Now, when two ranges are only up to 5 minutes apart, I'd like to merge them as well. **So the desired result would be:**

| contract_id | range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 09:00:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:45:00","2022-12-07 11:00:00") |

Working dbfiddle here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/owHkVaZ5

Is this achievable with SQL alone? Or do I need some kind of custom Postgres function for this? I've heard of an aggregator function, but never used one.

Comment: Good question! Obviously you can add 5 minutes to the end of all the ranges and merge, or add in little 5 minute ranges. But then you'll have the wrong upper times on everything and need a second stage to get the original times back. There are a couple of really knowledgeable people who watch the postgresql tag though, so hopefully one of them will see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard Huxton's idea of adding 5 minutes before you aggregate is good. Here is a simple implementation:

```
SELECT contract_id,
       tsrange(lower(u.r), upper(u.r) - INTERVAL '5 minutes')
FROM (SELECT contract_id,
             range_agg(tsrange("from", "to" + INTERVAL '5 minutes')) AS mr
      FROM time_entries
      GROUP BY contract_id) AS agg
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(agg.mr) AS u(r);
```

You need the `CROSS JOIN` because you want to join each group with all the multirange elements that belong to it. This "belong" is expressed by `LATERAL` which means that you refer to elements from the preceding `FROM` list entries in a later one. Essentially, that construct and the subquery are needed so that I can get the unnested ranges into the `FROM` expression where they belong, so that * can use them in the `SELECT` list.

`AS u(r)` is a table alias, that is an alias for a table name and the name of its columns at the same time.

Comment: This is awesome! Two things I don't quiet get are: 1. Why do I need a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`? And whats with the syntax `AS u(r);`?

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer.